# Force racket to accept recursive variable definition as a recursive function definition

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, racket

For fun I've created a bunch of functions in Racket that create and combine other functions.

Now I've defined a recursive function in terms of them:

```
(define (my-flatten2 struct)
  ((<?> pair?
       (<+> append <m>
            (</> map my-flatten2)
            (<Y> car cdr))
       list)
   struct))
```

I tried this first, but it didn't work (it gave me a can't reference identifier before its definition error):

```
(define my-flatten-error
  (<?> pair?
       (<+> append <m>
            (</> map my-flatten-error)
            (<Y> car cdr))
       list))
```

Can anyone explain why it didn't work, and whether or not there is a way to fix it.

For the record

- `<+>` is compose
- `<Y>` is create a function that applies a list of functions to one arg
- `</>` is partially apply
- `<?>` is choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Racket is an eager language; it evaluates arguments before passing them. So, your code does not work for the same reason that

```
(define p (add1 p))
```

doesn't work.

In this case, assuming that my-flatten error does turn out to be a function, it might be fairly easy to solve your problem just by delaying the evaluation of `my-flatten-error`:

```
(define my-flatten-error
  (<?> pair?
       (<+> append <m>
            (</> map (lambda args 
                       (apply my-flatten-error args)))
            (<Y> car cdr))
       list))
```

You can also hide the lambda using a macro:

```
(define-syntax delay-fn
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(delay-fn f) (lambda args (apply f args))]))


(define my-flatten-error
  (<?> pair?
       (<+> append <m>
            (</> map (delay-fn my-flatten-error))
            (<Y> car cdr))
       list))
```

... if you find that visually more pleasing.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense